# Hot to Check if the Value for particular node in XML exist or not

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument

The xml is loaded in a file called loadxml

```
<?xml version="1.0”?>
<GetUserProfileResponse>
  <User>
    <UserID>sonishopcom</UserID>
  </User>
  <User>
    <UserID>guru</UserID>
  </User>
</GetUserProfileResponse>
```

I am stuck with a simple Query.

I want to check in php if a particular value of the element exist or not in if() Statement
Like for example the UserID sonishopcom i need check.

```
 $userID = 'test';
 $datta = simplexml_load_file('loadxml');
```

Comment: What i am doing is using an array to save the node value and then using `in_array()` to search. This seems very efficiency killing option but i dont find way to search xml element value.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, what you pasted is not a valid xml document since the root of the xml is `</GetUserProfileResponse>` instead of `<GetUserProfileResponse>`

Once that is valid though:

```
$data = simplexml_load_file('loadxml');
if(isset($data[0]->User->UserID)) { echo "UserID is set"; }
```

The above would return if the first User's ID is set.

Comment: Yes it was a mistake and corrected for the same. I am basically getting user id save in an xml format just to avoid saving repeated entry i just want to check the xml string if the id exist or not if not then save it else prompt message as of now for test.

Comment: It would be easier to resolve if your xml nodes were written as such : `<User id="sonishopcom" /><User id="guru" />` because then you could search for the specific node containing that ID much more quickly. As it stands you will need to do a foreach loop on user nodes and return true if the string matches with the current item in said loop.

Comment: I agree to what you just mentioned, but the data which i am getting is directly from API and thus want to save in original format as imported that is in XML. So that if i need to Parse or extract data i can easily do so with custom script. I think there should definitely a way to check the value of element and return bool.

Comment: I just explained how to do that :p `As it stands you will need to do a foreach loop on user nodes and return true if the string matches with the current item in said loop.` There is no method for searching the value of a node, only searching for a node containing an attribute; very similar to how you can't select dom elements in css without selectors.

Answer (score 0):

What i am doing is using an array to save the node value and then using in_array() to search. This seems very efficiency killing option but i dont find way to search xml element value.